# How to Animate Button FontSize in Wpf?

Tags: wpf, animation

I have one Button Name Button1. I want to change this button font size in animation. So I wrote code in Window_Loaded function.

```
 DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation(0, 25, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
            //da.TargetPropertyType = "Width";            
            da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
            button1.BeginAnimation(Button.FontSizeProperty, da);
```

But I have got an Error-

> Cannot animate the 'FontSize' property on a
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Button' using a
>   'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'. For details see the
>   inner exception.

1) How to Animate Button Font Size?
2) What are the properties I have to Animate in Button?

Comment: Can you please read the inner exception, and post it here as well ... it might be ... helpful ... you know ... :)

Comment: Where Can I see the InnerException @Noctis

Comment: From memory, When you get the exception, in visual studio, you can click on the "more details", and one of the fields is "inner exception", you can toggle that to see more

Comment: {"The animation(s) applied to the 'FontSize' property calculate a current value of '0', which is not a valid value for the property."} This is the Inner exception sir. Invalid Operation Excepton

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this in xaml:

```
<Window...>
  <Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Duration="00:00:1">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="button1" From="6" To="25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Window.Triggers>
```

---

> 2) What are the properties I have to Animate in Button?

Target of Animation does not have to be a `DependencyProperty` if that's what you're thinking. All properties can be the animation target. Although standard Animation classes does not support some types.

for example Background. you can animate `Background.Color` using `ColorAnimation` but not `Background` itself because there's no `BrushAnimation`. however you can implement custom animation for such properties.

Comment: Have you Tried this code sir. Bzs while Implementing this code I got an error. Cannot convert string 'Loaded' in attribute 'RoutedEvent' to object of type 'System.Windows.RoutedEvent'. RoutedEventConverter cannot convert from System.String.  Error at object 'System.Windows.EventTrigger' in markup file 'WpfApplication1;component/window1.xaml'.

Comment: Your Code is worked Pls Changed RoutedEvent="Loaded" to  RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded".

Comment: Do you the Answer for What are the properties I have to Animate in Button?